# Kendo serverPaging using javascript and web API

Tags: javascript, kendo-grid

I have been having some issues getting the serverPaging option to work on kendoGrid. I have searched for several hours and just can't seem to get it work the way I expect it to. Here is what I have:

API Call:

```
[HTTPGet]
[Route("GetItemsByPage", Name = "GetItemsByPage"]
public IEnumerable<IItem> GetByPage(int id, int page, int pageSize)
{
return foo.GetByPage(id, page, pageSize);
}
```

JS:

```
var sharedDatasource = new kendo.data.Datasource({
    transport: {
        read: {
            url: "localhost:2222/api/product/Items/GetByPage/?id=38&page=1&pageSize=100"
            dataType: "json"
        }
    }, 
    schema: {
        total: // function to return total //
        // rest of schema info //
    },
    page: 1,
    pageSize: 100, 
    serverPaging: true
});
```

I then have the datasource attached to a grid div (all that shows up fine). It is just the server paging I have an issue with. I can use another api call to get all items, and then allow local paging, but I dont want to get all that data at once.

Answer (score 0):

You should setup [`transport.parameterMap` option](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/datasource#configuration-transport.parameterMap) on your DataSource

```
var sharedDatasource = new kendo.data.Datasource({
    transport: {
        read: {
            url: "localhost:2222/api/product/Items/GetByPage/?id=38&page=1&pageSize=100"
            dataType: "json"
        },
        parameterMap: function(data, type) {
        if (type == "read") {
            // send take as "$top" and skip as "$skip"
            return {
                pageSize: data.pageSize,
                page: data.page
            }
        }
    }

    }, 
    page: 1,
    pageSize: 100, 
    serverPaging: true
});
```

I don't know what is `id` in your code. But I hope you catch this idea.